# in ajax get a value upon clicking a button but it is in a loop

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".actdeact").on({
    click: function() {
        var id = $('.getfromhere').text();
        alert(id);


  {% for x in mylist %}
   <span class="getfromhere">{{x.id}}</span>
   <span class="btn btn-info actdeact">Deactivate</span>
  {% endfor %}`
```

`
If I write .text() I get the whole series of values of id.
If I write .html() I only get the first one
I want that upon clicking the button, only the value that corresponds to the row clicked is  sent to var id in the ajax code

```
I want to get just the value that corresponds to the row clicked, not the whole of the values of the loop.
```

Comment: Please add a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

You should use `this` keyword.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(documebt).on("click", ".actdeact",function() {

            var id = $(this).closest(".idlist").find('.getfromhere').text();
            alert(id);
    });
});

  {% for x in mylist %}
    <div class="idlist">
        <span class="getfromhere">{{x.id}}</span>
        <span class="btn btn-info actdeact">Deactivate</span>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}`
```

Comment: thank you, I will test it as soon as I get to my computer tonight. I was aware of the´" this"  option but, as you write, there was more to it than that, the "closest" modifier was  new to me.

Comment: It works, but only if both the button are next to each other. If they are separated by other divs, it won't work. I wrote them here together because there was no point in adding non-relevant code in between. This breaks my design unfortunately.

Comment: Then you can use onclick attribute for that span

Comment: Pass x.id in onclick function like onclick="callajax({{x.id}})" like this